# How do I convert postgreSQL results to JSON?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this sql

```sql
select post_id, tag 
from finalcache
order by tag, post_rank desc
```

It gives this results.

[image]

How do i get the results to look like this?

```json
{
   "Politics": ["1e4fd2c5-c32e-4e3f-91b3-45478bcf0185"],
   "Technology": [
      "1e4fd2c5-c32e-4e3f-91b3-45478bcf0185",
      "1e4fd2c5-c32e-4e3f-91b3-45478bcf0189",
      "1e4fd2c5-c32e-4e3f-91b3-45478bcf0186",
   ]
}
```

I have been trying different combinations of `json_build_object` and `json_agg` like this

```
select json_build_object(tag, json_agg(post_id))
from finalcache
group by tag, post_rank
order by tag, post_rank desc
```

But I am just not getting the correct response. Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is how you can do it :

```
select json_object_agg(tag,jposts) 
from (
     select tag, ARRAY_AGG(post_id) jposts
     from mytable 
     group by tag 
) t
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=60cc9bbc0b644b7ef100bd7ddc768cab)*

Comment: although i marked this one as correct, i was wondering if there was a way to make the root object into an object instead of an array?

Comment: i did... I asked it in this question, the root object in the question I asked was an object instead of an array...  But in your answer, the root object is an array.

Comment: @Justacoder   Oh i see, see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
WITH list AS
(
SELECT jsonb_agg(post_id) FILTER (WHERE tag = 'Politics') OVER () AS pol
     , jsonb_agg(post_id) FILTER (WHERE tag = 'Technology') OVER () AS tech 
  FROM finalcache
 ORDER BY post_rank desc
)
SELECT jsonb_build_object('Politics', l.pol, 'Technology', tech)
  FROM list AS l
```